# different values for jmeter ${__UUID} in loop

Tags: jmeter, guid

In my BSF preprocessor (language javascript), I am generating post data such as

```
 var totalCustomer = 2;
 var data = { "customers": [] };
 for(i=1; i<=totalCustomer; i++){

     // in all iteration getting same value for ${__UUID} 

     var customer = {
         "id": "${__UUID}"
     }
     data.customers.push(customer);
 }
 vars.putObject("data",JSON.stringify(data));
```

I guess it is compiled once and looked up for the value in subsequent iterations.

Is there any way I can generate different `guid` using `${__UUID}` for each iteration?

Comment: Hi , any feedback on answer? thx

Answer (score 6):

1. Replace `${__UUID}` with `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`. Don't inline JMeter variables and functions into script, it's not very good practice and may lead to unexpected behavior (as in your case). Particular for your scenario it's better to call [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) class methods directly.
2. Don't use BSF test elements, they're not very efficient from performance side of things. Consider using JSR223 test elements and Groovy language. See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) for explanation, benchmarks, groovy engine installation details and scripting best practices.

Comment: Not regarding 2 ( i will dig into perfomance side), can I use `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` when language in BSF preprocessor is javascript? I could use `"${__BeanShell(UUID.randomUUID().toString()}"` but its same as using `"${__UUID}"`

Comment: I don't get this answer at all. I'm using a HTTP Request and have replaced ${euid} so that it uses UUID.randomUUID().toString() but it just shoots an error and does not actually do anything. I have euid configured as a User Defined Variable. what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the "Parameters" field to pass ${__UUID}.

Then in your code, use:

> bsh.args[0]

Example:

[image]

This is when you're using the PreProcessor in a While Controller or Loop Controller.

But if you are speaking about a Beanshell code that contains a loop then just do:

> UUID.randomUUID().toString()

Of course ensure you import class:

> import java.util.UUID;

Comment: if you loop ex. `for(i=0;i<2;i++){log.error("Test:" + bsh.args[0])}` it produces the same UUID for each loop

Answer (score 6):

Write JSR223 PreProcessor using java language to generate UUID

```
vars.put("myUUID",UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

then access it in your javascript JSR223 PreProcessor.

```
var customer = {
     "id": "${myUUID}"
 }
```